# Spring Cloud Gateway and DiscoveryClient Routes

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to migrate a gateway that's working using `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul` to Spring Cloud Gateway, and I'm running into issues with request routing.

I ran across the following documentation regarding configuring predicates and filters for DiscoveryClient routes:

[Configuring Predicates and Filters For DiscoveryClient Routes](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_configuring_predicates_and_filters_for_discoveryclient_routes)

Here's a snippet from my Netflix Zuul configuration:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    account-service: /accounts/**
```

And here is a snippet from the Spring Cloud Gateway configuration where I'm attempting to configure an equivalent route:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: account-service-route
          uri: lb://account-service
          predicates:
          - Path=/accounts/**
```

I am using Spring Cloud Eureka as my Discovery Server (in a separate microservice), and I do not currently have any configuration as outlined in [Configuring Predicates and Filters For DiscoveryClient Routes](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_configuring_predicates_and_filters_for_discoveryclient_routes)

If I issue a request to `/accounts/***`, I receive a 404 reponse. If I change the Spring Cloud Gateway configuration to the following and issue the same request to `/account-service/***`, I receive a 403 Forbidden response:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: account-service-route
          uri: lb://account-service
          predicates:
          - Path=/account-service/**
```

I am suspecting that this has something to do with the default behavior of Spring Cloud Gateway with respect to how DiscoveryClient Routes are configured, but I don't see enough in the logs to point me in the right direction.

So, my question is this: When using Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring Cloud Eureka, is it required to make the configuration entries as outlined in [Configuring Predicates and Filters For DiscoveryClient Routes](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_configuring_predicates_and_filters_for_discoveryclient_routes)?

If so, can someone provide more explanation/clarity around what needs to be configured referring back to my route examples? Sorry if I'm missing something, but it's not obvious to me from what I read what exactly is needed with this configuration. For example, are the `spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates` and `spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters` configured in addition to or in place of the `spring.cloud.gateway.routes` predicates and filters?

If not, what other configuration(s) might I be missing?

I am on Spring Cloud Finchley.SR3/Spring Boot 2.0.8.RELEASE.

Answer (score 9):

Spring Cloud Gateway just enable request routing by default, and you have to enable discovery support explicitly. Try this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true  # default false
      routes:
        - id: account-service-route
          uri: lb://account-service #
          predicates:
            - Path=/account/**
```

Now you should be able access your service via `http://<gateway>/account-service/account/**`

Answer (score 1):

The setting

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true  # default false
```

will automatically create the route for *EVERY* service registered on Eureka, so you can access the *EVERY* service by `http://<gateway>/<service-name>/path`, and it will redirect to `lb://<service-name>/path` utilizing Load Balancer.
It will also remove the route from Gateway when service is de-registered at Eureka.

This setting is quite easy and fit to many situations. Just remember that routes will appear/disappear in ~30 seconds by default, and you may want to decrease that interval, to 5 secs for example with

```
eureka:
  client:
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5
```